# jQuery progress label not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a progress bar with jQuery that has a label written on it.
Without the label, it works as expected.

When I put the div with the label I can get the numbers to change (0 to 100%) but it doesn't animate anymore. The label changes, but the bar does not progress to the right.

I only have the javascript and the jsp below:

```
var progressLabel = $(".progressLabel", view.dialog);
$( "#progress" , view.dialog).progressbar({ value: percentComplete*100 , 
                 change: function() { progressLabel.text( $( "#progress" , 
                    view.dialog).progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
                 }});


<div id="progress">
    <div class="progressLabel">Importing Contacts</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `view.dialog`?

Comment: it's just for context, there are many divs and spans inside the larger jsp. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what could be happening is that when you add the label, that label is covering the progress bar background so the animation is happening but you can see it. Try adding this classes...

```
.ui-progressbar {
    position: relative;
}
.progressLabel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 4px;
}
```

... and if you verifiy that's the reason, just apply to your label the styles you want, paying attention to that.

I hope it helps...